# Removing sensitive URL data from borwser history

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser-history

I have a URL like this:

https://localhost:8081/test.php#param1=test&param2=sensitivedata

The "param2" parameter is somewhat sensitive so I don't want to have it in the browser's history.

I am using the following code:

`window.location.replace("#");`

This effectively remove the data from the user history in Chrome, but the data remains in Firefox.
Is there a way to do it in Firefox?

I have tried

`history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');`

but this does not work on Chrome or Firefox, the data remains on the user history.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just do a request to a "safe" route in your app and handle the logic in the background

Comment: The entry point for the user must be a single URL sent to the user by mail, like a "reset password" link, with the difference that the token will not expire so I do not want it to stay in hisotry if possible.

Comment: Not an answer, but you should try to avoid sending sensitive data using a GET request, especially when you're not using HTTPS. Use POST instead.

Comment: @Noodles yes I know, but this is the situation (see comment above). Regarding the https, of course the final version will have https.

Comment: Overall i don't think you should send sensitive data to the browser. Assume everything you send (including parameters in the URL) will be saved and played again. If you are headlining tokens, have a back-end to validate and expire them when necessary. Trusting that the browser history will be erased is very insecure.

Comment: How does this sensitive data end up in the browser's address bar? You talked about reset password email, if the link with sensitive data is really sent by email, how are you gonna remove it from their email?

Comment: This is an example to show the data is on an URL. This is a situation I cannot change and not under my control. So I want to remove it from as many places I can, and the browser history is one.

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions, the more we know about your situation the easier it is for us to find a solution you didn't thought of. For what you are asking, well... you can't. Note that even in Chrome, while they don't list it in the "History" panel, they still keep that URL in their internal history. If you try to place an `<a>` element pointing to that address, it will be shown as `:visited`, so one can certainly retrieve it.

Comment: @Kaiido yeah it seems you are right. There is a discussion here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=753264 , the behavior is different on each browser and this is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some research it seems it is not possible to do what I need. According to this [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=753264):

> For Firefox: history.replaceState creates NEW history items
>
> Chrome 28: Both location.replace and history.replaceState create new
>   entries in the global history UI. Chrome 30: location.replace updates
>   the existing entry, history.replaceState creates new entries Opera 12:
>   Neither location.replace nor history.replaceState create new entries
>   (but neither update the existing entry) Opera 15: Sometimes
>   location.replace creates a new entry, sometimes it updates an existing
>   one (no idea what the criteria are). history.replaceState always
>   creates a new entry. Safari 6: Both location.replace and
>   history.replaceState create new entries in the global history UI.

So it seems there is no reliable way to remove data from user's history.

Answer (score 0):

Mmh try these  solutions, perhaps together:

- javascript: use history.replaceState
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API
- server side: http headers: no cache headers
- server side: http headers: redirect types (302, 303, 307, 308)